# MYSQL Query to pull string data back from integer

Tags: mysql

Ok, my brain hurts, but hopefully I can make this make sense.

I have a say 3 tables. For this purpose we'll use products.

Products_type table would be like
ie, 1, car; 2, lorry; 3, bus

Manufacturer_table would be
1, Volvo; 2, Ford; 3, Scania;

and Model_table would be
1, XC90; 2, V70; 3, XC40; 4, some ford model; 5, some scania model

So the products table could show:
type, 1; manufacturer 1; model, 2 which would translate to Car, Volvo, V70

If I do a SELECT * on PRODUCTS, that is what I see, the integers. What is the best way to perform the query so that it actually looksup the other tables and gives the string values?

Comment: My brain hurts too.  You need to use a JOIN, there are plenty of good tutorials out there on how to use them.

Comment: Ah yes, I was thinking along the lines of JOINs and INNERJOINS from ye old SQL days. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` your products table to each of the other tables to get the names associated with each integer in the products table. Assuming your `products` table has fields called `type_id`, `manufacturer_id` and `model_id`, and each of the other tables has `id` and `name` fields, something like this should work:

```
SELECT t.type_name, m.manu_name, md.model_name
FROM products p
JOIN type t ON t.type_id = p.type_id
JOIN manufacturer m ON m.manu_id = p.manu_id
JOIN model md ON md.model_id = p.model_id
```

Comment: ok so I have the main PRODUCTS table with an fields id, type_id. manu_id and model_id. Then I have a TYPE table with type_id and type_name, a MANUFACTURER table with manu_id and manu_name and a MODEL table with model_id and model_name. Is that what you were suggesting?

Comment: sorry, I can't seem to get this to work.  SELECT type_name, manu_name, model_name from PRODUCTS JOIN type_id ON  products.id = type.id JOIN manu_id ON manufacturer.id = products.manu_id JOIN model_id ON model.id = products.model_id

Comment: @Lucero79 I've updated my answer based on the table and field names you have used in your comments. Can you give that a try?